# How to use Custom Fields on the envelope

Tags: docusignapi, electronic-signature

I am new to DOCUSIGN and learning the features of it.

I could see there is a feature to create custom Fields for a template.

I am not able to find the documentation about how to use custom fields in the envelope.

Is it possible to use the custom fields as a placeholder inside email to fill some data dynamically. So that the creator of envelope just fills in the information in the custom field and it will be used in the email body/subject etc..

is this possible.

need some advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Custom fields" in DocuSign exist at various levels -- i.e., *Envelope* Custom Fields, *Document* Custom Fields, *Recipient* Custom Fields, etc. -- and simply facilitate you being able to associate metadata you specify with a specific object.  For example, you might create an *Envelope Custom Field* called "CustId" and populate that field with the Id of the corresponding customer for each Envelope you create/send. Then, because you associated "CustId" value with each Envelope, you could later utilize this data for reporting purposes (for example: to find all envelopes associated with a particular customer).  Custom fields cannot facilitate the functionality you've inquired about.

It's not possible via DocuSign functionality to utilize 'placeholders' as you've described to dynamically inject Envelope-specific values into the Email Subject/Body. However, you could easily have your application collect the relevant information (perhaps from the sender via a webform, or via a database lookup if you're app already has the relevant info there), and then use that information to programmatically (in your code) assemble the complete Subject and Body for the email, before using an API call to create the Envelope (specifying Subject and Body as part of your API request).

Comment: Thanks. I was actually interested in finding out the way to see if it is already out of box with the Docusign UI. This explanation is very clear.